# data from android studio to matlab via bluetooth

Tags: android, matlab, bluetooth

I am new to android studios and I have the task to develop an app which transfers data from an app (Acceleration sensor data - i have created this app already which shows the data) to matlab (on the pc). 
I don't really know how I should do this. I've experimented a bit with bluetooth apps, but I don't have a clue how to connect to Matlab.
I would be greatful for your help.
Thanks in advance,
Annika

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can not speak to the android side of things, but MatLab can connect to generic devices with the UART interface, which is fairly low level.

The process with some microprocessors that I am using is to connect the device to the PC, and then note the Outgoing com port. 
(In windows 10, these can be found in Bluetooth settings -> More Bluetooth options)
Then you can use

```
s = serial('COM<what you found in settings>');
s.Baudrate=115200;
s.InputBufferSize = 100;
fopen(s{i});
serials = instrfindall;
```

to open an connection. The critical command is `serial`, the other parameters depend on your device/ configuration. Sometimes there can be issues, in which case one options is to build a loop that tries again until it works.

You then collect the data sent via UART via

```
  flushinput(serials);
  temp = fscanf(serials,'%s');
```

and then split the string. If data is sent continuously, you wrap this into a while loop.

After you are done, you can clean up via

```
 fclose(s{i});
 delete(instrfind)
 instrreset
```

It should be noted, that establishing a connection takes longer, the more enabled COM ports there are. So it might be worth disabling all those you don't need.

For more specific things matlab can do, check out [What Is the MATLAB Serial Port Interface](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introduction_f105659.html)